# If I have the contents of a zipfile in a Python string, can I decompress it without writing it to a file?

Tags: python

I've written some Python code that fetches a zip file from the web and into a string:

```
In [1]: zip_contents[0:5]
Out[1]: 'PK\x03\x04\x14'
```

I see there's a zipfile library, but I'm having trouble finding a function in it that I can just pass a bunch of raw zip data. It seems to want to read it from a file.

Do I really need to dump this to a temp file, or is there a way around it?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

[zipfile.ZipFile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile) accepts any file-like object:

> class zipfile.ZipFile(file, …)
>
> Open a ZIP file, where file can be a **path to a file** (a string), a **file-like object** or a path-like object.

So you can use [BytesIO (3.x)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) or [StringIO (2.x)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
# Modern Python 3.x
from io import BytesIO
import zipfile

fp = BytesIO(b'PK\x03\x04\x14')
zfp = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, "r")
```

```
# Legacy Python 2.x
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except:
    from StringIO import StringIO
import zipfile

fp = StringIO('PK\x03\x04\x14')
zfp = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, "r")
```

Answer (score 6):

Wrap your string in a [cStringIO](http://docs.python.org/library/stringio.html#module-cStringIO) object.  It looks, acts, and quacks like a file object, but resides in memory.

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, python changed a little bit since the accepted answer.

The cStringIO lib changed name since python 3.0 (more details in https://stackoverflow.com/a/18284900/8647541)

Just try the following :

```
import io
import zipfile

fp = io.StringIO('PK\x03\x04\x14') # or io.BytesIO if you have a Bytes object
zfp = zipfile.ZipFile(fp, "r")
zfp.extractall("./extract_folder") # extract zip in a `extract_folder` folder
```