# Reading a JSON file from S3 using Python boto3

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I kept following JSON in the S3 bucket `test`:

```
{
  'Details': "Something" 
}
```

I am using the following code to read this JSON and printing the key `Details`:

```
s3 = boto3.resource('s3',
                    aws_access_key_id=<access_key>,
                    aws_secret_access_key=<secret_key>
                    )
content_object = s3.Object('test', 'sample_json.txt')
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_content = json.loads(repr(file_content))
print(json_content['Details'])
```

And I am getting an error `'string indices must be integers'`.
I don't want to download the file from S3 and then read it.

Comment: Remove the `repr`.

Comment: @AlexHall Initially i tried by removing `repr `, but it didn't work, it is giving **ValueError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes**

Comment: I resolved the problem.. JSON should have attributes enclosed in double quotes.. i changes my json format

Comment: Which line are you getting an error on? Split up that line. `file_content = content_object...` is 4 steps in one line. For now, split that up into 4 separate lines with 4 intermediate variables. Then see which line fails.

Comment: All I needed for my issue was '.read().decode('utf-8')' so thank you for asking (-;

Answer (score 111):

As mentioned in the comments above, `repr` has to be removed and the `json` file has to use **double quotes** for attributes. Using this file on aws/s3:

```
{
  "Details" : "Something"
}
```

and the following Python code, it works:

```
import boto3
import json

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

content_object = s3.Object('test', 'sample_json.txt')
file_content = content_object.get()['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
json_content = json.loads(file_content)
print(json_content['Details'])
# >> Something
```

Comment: Note to others: https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/s3.html#object `s3.Object('bucketName', 'keyName')` so an example to get the file `s3://foobarBucketName/folderA/folderB/myFile.json` would be `s3.Object('foobarBucketName', 'folderA/folderB/myFile.json')`

Answer (score 50):

The following worked for me.

```
# read_s3.py

from boto3 import client

BUCKET = 'MY_S3_BUCKET_NAME'
FILE_TO_READ = 'FOLDER_NAME/my_file.json'
client = client('s3',
                 aws_access_key_id='MY_AWS_KEY_ID',
                 aws_secret_access_key='MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
                )
result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE_TO_READ) 
text = result["Body"].read().decode()
print(text['Details']) # Use your desired JSON Key for your value
```

**Further Improvement**

Let's call the above code snippet as `read_s3.py`.

It is not good idea to hard code the AWS Id & Secret Keys directly. For best practices, you can consider either of the followings:

(1) Read your AWS credentials from a json file (`aws_cred.json`) stored in your local storage:

```
from json import load
from boto3 import client
...
credentials = load(open('local_fold/aws_cred.json'))
client = client('s3',
                 aws_access_key_id=credentials['MY_AWS_KEY_ID'],
                 aws_secret_access_key=credentials['MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                )
```

(2) Read from your environment variable (my preferred option for deployment):

```
    from os import environ
    client = boto3.client('s3',              
                         aws_access_key_id=environ['MY_AWS_KEY_ID'],
                           aws_secret_access_key=environ['MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
                         )
```

Let's prepare a shell script called `read_s3_using_env.sh` for setting the environment variables and add our python script (`read_s3.py`) there as follows:

```
# read_s3_using_env.sh
export MY_AWS_KEY_ID='YOUR_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'
export MY_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY='YOUR_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'
# execute the python file containing your code as stated above that reads from s3
python read_s3.py # will execute the python script to read from s3
```

Now execute the shell script in a terminal as follows:

```
sh read_s3_using_env.sh
```

Comment: You don't need to specify credentials on the client initialization, it's automatically handled by the boto3 and other AWS SDKs. Which allow users to automatically authenticate with whatever way they choose to (could be IAM roles instead)

Comment: @Hafizur Rahman- The variable `text` here is a string, so ```print(text['Details'])``` will not work. I believe you would have to update the code snippet accordingly.

Answer (score 39):

Wanted to add that the `botocore.response.streamingbody` works well with `json.load`:

```
import json
import boto3

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')

obj = s3.Object(bucket, key)
data = json.load(obj.get()['Body'])
```

Comment: note: json.loads (with s) will not work here

Answer (score 5):

You can use the below code in AWS Lambda to read the JSON file from the S3 bucket and process it using python.

```
import json
import boto3
import sys
import logging

# logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

VERSION = 1.0

s3 = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = 'my_project_bucket'
    key = 'sample_payload.json'
    
    response = s3.get_object(Bucket = bucket, Key = key)
    content = response['Body']
    jsonObject = json.loads(content.read())
    print(jsonObject)
```

Answer (score 4):

I was stuck for a bit as the decoding didn't work for me (s3 objects are gzipped).

Found this discussion which helped me:
[Python gzip: is there a way to decompress from a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1543652/python-gzip-is-there-a-way-to-decompress-from-a-string?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```
import boto3
import zlib

key = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["object"]["key"]
bucket_name = event["Records"][0]["s3"]["bucket"]["name"]

s3_object = S3_RESOURCE.Object(bucket_name, key).get()['Body'].read()

jsonData = zlib.decompress(s3_object, 16+zlib.MAX_WBITS)
```

If youprint jsonData, you'll see your desired JSON file! If you are running test in AWS itself, be sure to check CloudWatch logs as in lambda it wont output full JSON file if its too long.

Answer (score 1):

If your json file looks like this:

```json
{
    "test": "test123"
}
```

You can access it like a `dict` like this:

```py
BUCKET="Bucket123"

def get_json_from_s3(key: str):
    """
    Retrieves the json file containing responses from s3. returns a dict

    Args:
        key (str): file path to the json file

    Returns:
        dict: json style dict
    """
    data = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=key)
    json_text = data["Body"].read().decode("utf-8")
    json_text_object = json.loads(json_text)
    return json_text_object
test_dict = get_json_from_s3(key="test.json")
print(test_dict["test"])
```

Comment: The variable names are misleading here. `json_text_bytes` contains the JSON test, while `json_text` contains the JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy to do with [cloudpathlib](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/), which supports S3 and also Google Cloud Storage and Azure Blob Storage. Here's a sample:

```py
import json
from cloudpathlib import CloudPath


# first, we'll write some json data so then we can later read it
CloudPath("s3://mybucket/asdf.json").write_text('{"field": "value"}')
#> 18


# read data from S3
data = json.loads(
    CloudPath("s3://mybucket/asdf.json").read_text()
)

# look at the data
data
#> {'field': 'value'}

# access it now that it is loaded in Python
data["field"] == "value"
#> True
```

This comes with a few added benefits in terms of setting [particular options](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/other_client_settings/) or [different authentication mechanisms](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/authentication/) or keeping a [persistent cache](https://cloudpathlib.drivendata.org/stable/caching/) so you don't always need to redownload from S3.