# read json file with Python from S3 into sagemaker notebook

Tags: python, json, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I want to read a json file from S3 into a sagemaker notebook.

I can do this with pandas with this code, and this works without error :

```
import json
import pandas as pd
import boto3


prefix_source = 'folder'

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
my_bucket_source = s3.Bucket('bucket_source')

for obj in my_bucket_source.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix_source):
        data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(obj.bucket_name, obj.key)
        data = pd.read_json(data_location, lines = True )
        display(data.head())
```

but I don't want to use pandas, I want to use Python

I tried this code

```
for obj in my_bucket_source.objects.filter(Prefix=prefix_source):
        data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(obj.bucket_name, obj.key)
        with open(data_location, 'r') as f:
            array = json.load(f)
            display(array)
```

I got this error :

**IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Comment: try using array = json.loads(file.read())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Json.load() expect a local file system path "/...", not an "s3://" URI.
See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47121263