# Read a JSON from S3

Tags: python, amazon-s3

I am new to python and following the answers from an [existing_post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40995251/reading-an-json-file-from-s3-using-python-boto3/47121263) I am trying to read a json file from amazon S3 like this:

```
  import boto3
  import os
    BUCKET = 'my_bucket'
    FILE_TO_READ = 'file.json'
    client = boto3.client('s3',
                           aws_access_key_id=os.environ.my_key,
                           aws_secret_access_key=os.environ.my_secret_key
                         )
    result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key='file') 
    text = result["Body"].read().decode()
    print(text['key']) # Use your desired JSON Key for your value
```

However I am receiving the following error:

```
NoSuchKey: An error occurred (NoSuchKey) when calling the GetObject operation: The specified key does not exist.
```

Can someone please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is saying that that your key does not exist. I see that you already have the key "file.json" so I assume it exists. I would assume that you have your filed stored like this `bucket/same_file/file.json` . If this is the case try this:

```
import json
import boto3
s3_obj =boto3.client('s3')
s3_clientobj = s3_obj.get_object(Bucket='your_bucket', Key='file/file.json')
s3_clientdata = s3_clientobj['Body'].read().decode('utf-8')
print("printing s3_clientdata")
print(s3_clientdata)
```

If you want to do data manipualation, a more pythonic soution would be:

```
fs = s3fs.S3FileSystem()
with fs.open('yourbucket/file/your_json_file.json', 'rb') as f:
    s3_clientdata = json.load(f)
#Convert to df
df = pd.DataFrame(s3_clientdata,index=[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are retrieving the object with key "file" in

```
result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key='file')
```

I think you where meaning something like:

```
result = client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET, Key=FILE_TO_READ)
```

See the [get_object reference](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) for further details

Comment: Error says "The specified key does not exist". 

Try: Amazon console > S3 > Your bucket > Click on the file you want to download > Overview > Key.

You should try using that key