# Adding zip file from a response to Django FileField

Tags: python, django, zip

Currently I am making a call to an API an that sends back a zip file. When using `requests`

```
res = requests.post('http://url/to/api', files={'file_pro': *my_file*})
```

I am able to get a successful response with the returned zip as a string. 
When I examine the contents of my res.contents I get :

```
PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x0c\x83HH\xba\xd2\xf1\t\xa1\x00\x00\x00\x04\x01\x00\x00....05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00\x08\x00\x1e\x02\x00\x00$\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00
```

It looks like its returning the zip file as a string. I looked at this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313845/if-i-have-the-contents-of-a-zipfile-in-a-python-string-can-i-decompress-it-with) to attempt to transform this string into the original zip file. Specifically I wrote:

```
my_file = UploadedFile(file=File(zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO.StringIO(res.content)),'r'))
my_file.save()
```

Upon trying to save I get the following error:

```
KeyError: 'There is no item named 65536 in the archive'
```

My ultimate goal is to bind this zip file to an `UploadedFile`

```
class UploadedFile(BaseModel):
  file = models.FileField(upload_to='/path', max_length=255)
```

If I use a html form to reach this API my browser automatically downloads the zip after the request is successful. Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `requests` library allows you get the response back as binary data - http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#binary-response-content.

You don't need to use `ZipFile` to reconstruct the zip, the data passed back should already be the bytes of a zip file.

```
from django.core.files.uploadedfile import SimpleUploadedFile

# res.content is the bytes of your API response
res = request.post('http://url/to/api', files={'file_pro': *myfile*})
my_file = SimpleUploadedFile('temp.zip', res.content)

# verify the zip file
assert zipfile.is_zipfile(my_file)

# finally save the file
uploaded_file = UploadedFile(file=my_file)
uploaded_file.save()

# play around with the zipfile
with zipfile.ZipFile(uploaded_file.file) as my_zip_file:
    print(my_zip_file.infolist())
```

Note that `zipfile.ZipFile` takes either a filename or a file-like object. In your question, you passed a string/bytes directly into it.

Also consider renaming the `UploadedFile` model, as Django already has one built-in at `django.core.files.uploadedfile.UploadedFile`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It makes sense. The part of a confused about is your use of ```SimpleUploadedFile``` There's not a lot of documentation on this object. Is there any other way to do this without having to to use SimpleUploadedFile?

Comment: A `SimpleUploadedFile` is a subclass of `File` in Django (which you used in your question) and the implementation of it uses Python's `BytesIO`. If you don't want to use `SimpleUploadedFile`, you can achieve the same effect by doing `File(BytesIO(res.content))`.

Comment: I used ```ContentFile``` and that worked too. Thanks for your help.