# The `File is not a zip file` error for the output of `git show` by GitPython

Tags: python, git, plugins

#### The script to reproduce the issue

Save this code as a shell script and run it. The code should report the `File is not a zip file` error.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

mkdir foo
cd foo

pip install --user GitPython

echo foo > a
zip a.zip a

# -t option validates the zip file.
# See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/197127/test-integrity-of-zip-file
unzip -t a.zip

git init
git add a.zip
git commit -m 'init commit'

cat << EOF > test.py
from git import Repo
import zipfile
from io import StringIO

repo = Repo('.', search_parent_directories=True)

raw = repo.git.show("HEAD:a.zip")

z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(raw), "r")
EOF

python3 test.py
```

#### Original Question

I'm writing a Krita plugin for viewing files in previous commits of a Git repository, and I want to get the thumbnail file of a Krita file. To do so, I'm trying to get a file with `git show`, unzip it because a Krita file is [a Zip file](https://docs.krita.org/en/general_concepts/file_formats/file_kra.html), and get `preview.png` or `mergedimage.png`.

```
%unzip image.kra
Archive:  image.kra
 extracting: mimetype                
  inflating: maindoc.xml             
  inflating: documentinfo.xml        
  inflating: preview.png             
  inflating: image/layers/layer2     
  inflating: image/layers/layer2.defaultpixel  
  inflating: image/layers/layer2.icc  
  inflating: image/annotations/icc   
  inflating: mergedimage.png         
  inflating: image/animation/index.xml
```

We can get the `.kra` file from the Git repository [as `str`](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/tutorial.html#using-git-directly) with GitPython. However, I can't parse the file with `zipfile.ZipFile` as it says `File is not a zip file`. (This code is based on [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1313868/13132898))

```py
from git import Repo
import zipfile
from io import StringIO

repo = Repo('.', search_parent_directories=True)

raw = repo.git.show("HEAD~:image.kra")

z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(raw), "r")
```

will emit

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/hiroki/krita_question/test.py", line 11, in <module>
    z = zipfile.ZipFile(StringIO(raw), "r")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1257, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.9/zipfile.py", line 1324, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

I believe this is a valid Krita file because I can restore the file with `git show` on the command line. So,

```
%git show HEAD~:image.kra > prev.kra
%krita prev.kra
```

works correctly. Unzipping the file works too.

Why can't I parse the `git show` output as a Zip file?

`git log --stat|grep -v 'Author'`:

```
commit b96d915862b39a204a9f4350e7e56634b6fcfe0b
Date:   Wed Mar 30 14:44:02 2022 +0900

    chore: add

 ls | 231 +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
 1 file changed, 231 insertions(+)

commit 619984a842c6c2daf31559c1979f91227a323648
Date:   Wed Mar 30 14:43:58 2022 +0900

    chore: add

 image.kra | Bin 0 -> 777685 bytes
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
```

#### Versions

Python: 3.9.9

GitPython: 3.1.27

Krita: 5.0.2

Linux 5.15.16-gentoo

All files are created in Linux.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Update

GitPython version 3.1.28 (not yet released) should add the [`strip_newline_in_stdout` option](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/pull/1423). If the option is set to `False`, the trailing `\n` of the stdout of any commands run by `repo.git.foobar` will be preserved.

```py
raw = repo.git.show("HEAD~:image.kra", strip_newline_in_stdout=False)
```

#### Original answer

It seems that this is caused by the [GitPython's bug](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython/issues/1377). It truncated the last `\n` of the output of `git show` and made the file invalid.

I changed the code to use `subprocess.Popen` and `ZipFile` succeeded.

```py
import zipfile
from io import BytesIO
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen(["git", "show", "HEAD:a.zip"], stdout = subprocess.PIPE)

out, _ = p.communicate()

z = zipfile.ZipFile(BytesIO(out), "r")
```